# nested xsd: Cannot resolve the name ... to a type defintion component

Tags: java, xsd, namespaces

My webservice should be able to validate xml-input against a schema(request.xsd). The complextyped only element in the schema owns different subelements of types which are defined in other xsds. I am importing all thess xsds. At the end however element type cannot be resolved.
this ist my "request.xsd":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:fe="http://www.some.dir/featurenamespace"
    xmlns="http://this.is.my.space" 
    targetNamespace="http://this.is.my.space" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:import schemaLocation=" http://www.some.dir/featurenamespace/cmplxtypes.xsd " 
    namespace=" http://www.some.dir/featurenamespace"/>

<xs:element name="elem1" type="request"/>

  <xs:complexType name="request">
    <xs:complexContent>
       <xs:extension base="fe:complexElement">
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="record" type="fe:complexElement "/>
          </xs:sequence>
       </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

This is the schema (e.g. cmplxtypes.xsd) where the type 'complexElement' is defined:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:fe="http://www.some.dir/featurenamespace"  
  xmlns:ofe ="http://www.some.dir/otherfeaturenamespace" 
  targetNamespace="http://www.some.dir/featurenamespace" 
  version="1.1.0" 
  elementFormDefault="qualified" 
  attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:include schemaLocation="fe_types.xsd" />
<xs:import schemaLocation="ofe_types.xsd" namespace="http://www.some.dir/otherfeaturenamespace"/>

<xs:complexType name="complexElement">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="feature" type="fe:FeatureType "/>  
    <xs:element name="otherfeature" type="ofe:otherFeatureType"/>                
 </sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

The files: cmplxtypes.xsd, fe_types.xsd and ofe_types.xsd share the same namespace.

Now, trying to validate myxml against request.xsd I get: cannot resolve 'complexElement' to a 'type defintion' component.
I do appreciate any help.

Comment: it would be great if you could post your xml file and also ofe_types.xsd and fe_types.xsd. Note that the fe and ofe prefixes seem not to be bound to the same namespace, which is in contradiction with the text.

Answer (score 0):

There are several inconsistencies in the schemas that may explain the error.

1. request.xsd doesn't appear to be importing cmplxtypes.xsd, where fe:complexElement is defined.

   ```
   <xs:import
     schemaLocation="http://www.some.dir/featurenamespace/cmplxtypes.xsd"
     namespace=" http://www.some.dir/featurenamespace" />
   ```
2. cmplxtypes.xsd includes ofe_types.xsd even though the namespace does not match according to the import in request.xsd. Namespaces much match when including other schemas (or the included schema must have no target namespace).

Comment: Thank you for  your attention. I did correct my mistakes in the above code. The error (cannot resolve...) remains the same. Now I'll try to unmarshall that xml-input via JAXB to a java object and see whether it does or not.

Comment: That's strange, because I could validate successfully with oXygen, inferring the other documents. If you can provide us with all files, we can try to reproduce your error more closely.

Comment: I am not allowed to share the files so I reconstruct the structure for the question. I guesss the problem is how I create the java classes from the schema because now -bevor calling validator- I use JAXBContext-Unmarschaller to read the xml ending up with the following unmarschall-exception:  unexpected element (uri:"", local:"elem1"). expected elements are < (somenamespace)elem1> .  I need good books about schema, JXC and namsapces :(